# Add column names to a H5PY dataset

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to add column names to a pre-exisiting dataset. I have three columns and want each to have a name.

```
with h5py.File(path, "w") as f:
    x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    y1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    z1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    namesList = ['ID', 'Name', 'Path']
    ds_dt = np.dtype({'names': namesList, 'formats': ['S32'] * 3})

    a = f.create_dataset("s", (1, 3), maxshape=(None, None), dtype='S32')
    print(a[0,0])
    for i in range(len(x1)):
        a.resize(a.shape[0] + 1, axis=0)
        a[i, 0] = x1[i]
        a[i, 1] = y1[i]
        a[i, 2] = z1[i]
    
    array = a[:]
    rec_arr = [row for row in array]
    
    b = f.create_dataset("s2", data=rec_arr, dtype=ds_dt, maxshape=(None, None))
```

This is the dataset that I want to add the column names:
[image: This is the dataset that I want to add to]

This is what I get when I try to add the names:
[image: This is what I get]

Comment: Based on a recent post it appears you figure out how to create names for your fields/columns. Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the modifications to get the code above to work as described. You had the right idea creating the recarray dtype. You need to use it when you create `rec_arr`, and/or when you create an empty dataset. (If you use `data=` to create and populate the dataset with data, h5py will figure out the dtype and initial shape "auto-magically". You still need to define `maxshape` if you want to resize later.)

This creates 2 different datasets, both with the same dtype:

1. The first is empty and references `ds_dt`.
2. The second is populated with data by referencing `data=rec_arr`

Code below:

```
with h5py.File(path, "w") as f:
    x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    y1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    z1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    namesList = ['ID', 'Name', 'Path']
    ds_dt = np.dtype({'names': namesList, 'formats': ['S32'] * 3}) 
    
    rec_arr = np.empty(shape=(len(x1)), dtype=ds_dt)
    rec_arr['ID'] = x1
    rec_arr['Name'] = y1
    rec_arr['Path'] = z1

    # create empty dataset with dtype defined by ds_dt
    f.create_dataset("empty", dtype=ds_dt, shape=(len(x1),), maxshape=(None,))
    # Create dataset and populate with data from rec_arr
    f.create_dataset("data", data=rec_arr, maxshape=(None,))
```